# caches_page :all

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, page-caching

Is there any way to tell Rails 3 to cache all pages in a given controller without having to list them all when calling `caches_page`? I tried `caches_page :all`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Kind of a bug of the implementation, but I just tried it and it works on Rails 3.0.6:

```
caches_page :except => []
```

Comment: Probably the cleanest way of handling it

Comment: I also tried in Rails 3.2.17 and it is working. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can always do some hack like:

```
(YourController.public_instance_methods - ApplicationController.public_instance_methods).each do |x|
  caches_page x.to_sym
end
```